# How to call parent class member function from an overloaded function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

I created one new class which is publicly inherited from the string class. I wish to overload the  `<` (less than) operator in the derived class. But from the overloaded function I need to call the parent class `<` operator. What is the syntax for calling this function? I would like to implement the operator as a member function if possible.

In Java there is `super` keyword for this.

My code is given below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;    
class mystring:public string
    {
     bool operator<(const mystring ms)
     {
      //some stmt;
      //some stmt;
      //call the overloaded <( less than )operator in the string class and return the value
      }

    };
```

Comment: Is `string` `std::string`?

Comment: Thank you for the link.I need the syntax for calling the less than operator in the parent class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` doesn't have a member overload of `operator<`, there is a free function template for `operator<` that operates on `std::string`. You should consider making your `operator<` a free function to. To call the `operator<` that operates on `std::string`, you can use references.

E.g.:

```
const std::string& left = *this;
const std::string& right = ms;
return left < right;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This one works perfectly.
Could you please answer one more doubt.If it is a free function template ,by default It should work for mystring also.But compiler gives error when I delete the operator < function from mystr.

Comment: @AbleJohnson: What error does the compiler give and what does the code that gives this error actually look like?

Comment: `#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;    
class mystring:public string
    {
 
     };
int main()
{
 mystring a,b;
 cout<<a<b;
 return(0);
}`

This is my code.The compiler gives a very long page of error

Comment: @AbleJohnson: You probably meant `cout<<(a<b);` (`<<` binds more tightly than `<`) but telling me that the error was long still doesn't give me any clue as to its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a base class operawtor is easy if you realize that it is just a function with a funny name:

```
bool operator<(const mystring ms)
{
  //some stmt;
  //some stmt;
  return string::operator<(ms);
}
```

Alas, that does not work with `std::string` because `operator<` is not a member function, but a free function. Something like:

```
namespace std
{
    bool operator<(const string &a, const string &b);
}
```

The rationale is the same, call the funny named function:

```
bool operator<(const mystring ms)
{
  //some stmt;
  //some stmt;
  operator<(*this, ms);
}
```

Comment: `std::string` doesn't have a member `operator<`.

Comment: I tried that
error: ‘operator<’ is not a member of ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’

Comment: Ops! You are right, it is a free function! not a member one! Correcting the answer...